# Unable to "inspect background page" with nw.js, debugger shows empty screen

Tags: javascript, chromium, nwjs

The documentation says "check your proxy settings for bypassing localhost" but doesn't provide context. I can hit `localhost` servers I run without a problem.

From "https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4578" I try this:

```
var thegui = require('nw.gui');
var win = thegui.Window.get();
win.on("devtools-opened", function(url) {
    document.getElementById('devtools').src = url;
});
chrome.developerPrivate.openDevTools({
    renderViewId: -1,
    renderProcessId: -1,
    extensionId: chrome.runtime.id
});
win.showDevTools();
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Quantum Pilot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "game.html",
  "window" : {
    "toolbar": true
  },
  "chromium-args": "--enable-logging=stderr"
}
```

When I run the app, right clicking does not give me option to "inspect background page".

The debugger shows a chrome devtools frontend (??? why is this hitting a remote server???) with nothing to show

[image]

I am getting a crash after running my code for a bit and I want to debug why with the console.

EDIT

I tried copying the SDK build `nwjs` executable replacing my old `nwjs` executable inside the .app package.

I copied over chromedriver, minidump_stackwalk, nwjc and payload from the nwjs sdk build too.

I get a crash when I run the app. https://gist.github.com/quantumproducer/4a03b6abc8e7401a3633824edae62c54

Comment: Hi, am wondering if you ever solved the problem. thanks.

Comment: @JamesWong hi,  I vbelieve this was running on a raspberry pi. I did not, it's an issue iwth ELF on PI, I decided touse a chromimu webapp (just html page) with hardwired width and height